# Enums Inheritance not Working in Python3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I've wrote below code, works fine in Python3.7

```py
from enum import Enum

class UserRoles(Enum):
    ADMIN = 'ADMIN'
    MANAGER = 'MANAGER'
    MEMBER = "MEMBER"


class AuthorRoles(UserRoles, Enum):
    pass
```

Getting below error in Python3.8

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 146, in __prepare__
    metacls._check_for_existing_members(cls, bases)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 527, in _check_for_existing_members
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: AuthorRoles: cannot extend enumeration 'UserRoles'
```

**Note:** I'm aware that inheriting is not recommended according to python docs

just curious what caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enum inheritance is not allowed, but it worked in `python3.7` due to this [Bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue?@action=redirect&bpo=41517)

The issue was fixed in `python3.8`, so I got the above error.